# Stripe API: expand nested card element

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I use a Stripe Checkout session to set up a payment intent and want to expand the card property, nested three levels deep.

According to [the documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/expand), I can expand a property and a sub-property with dot-notation:

```
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(session_id, {
    expand: ["setup_intent.payment_method"]
  });
```

Then I receive this response:

```
{
  id: 'cs_test...",
  ...
  setup_intent: {
    id: 'seti_1MDYkcAphQbVdSksInihHamA',
    ...
    payment_method: {
      id: 'pm_1MDYknAphQbVdSks1a1eohA7',
      object: 'payment_method',
      billing_details: [Object],
      card: [Object],
      ...
      type: 'card'
    },
  ...
}
```

I would like to also expand the card to get the fingerprint and check if it is a duplicate. So I use this:

```
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(session_id, {
    expand: ["setup_intent.payment_method.card"]
  });
```

But the result is the same as above: `card: [Object]` and it does not show the card's fingerprint.

The request does not throw an error on Stripe's end, so I presume that the syntax is correct.

Is this lack of expansion due to being in test mode? If not, how can I tell Stripe to include the card's fringerprint?

Comment: You are probably printing out that value, right? You'll find the card object documentation here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-card

Comment: You are right: the value of `card` was in the object but the console didn't print it out fully. The fingerprint is in `setup_intent.payment_method.card.fingerprint;`. Can you write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that you are printing out a nested object. Even if the printed result is shown that way, the object properties are there and you can still use them.

You can confirm by running:

```js
console.log(setup_intent.payment_method.card.fingerprint);
```

You'll find the card object fingerprint and documentation here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-card